# Azure AD - Switch User Identity In WebAPI to Consume Downstream Service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, access-token, adal

In Azure AD I have the following scenario:

- Single page application (consumes) > WebAPI 1 (consumes) > WebAPI 2

Authenticated user consumes WebAPI 1 under their identity.

Some operations in WebAPI 1 need to consume WebAPI 2 under a different identity (service-to-service), thus need to request an access token under a different identity (service account). I am using ADAL.NET in the WebAPI.

I've read through the MS Documentation ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols)) to understand the different scenarios/protocols but I cannot see anything that fits this scenario where I need to request an access token on-behalf-of a different user to that of the user who is already authenticated.

I looked into using ADAL to authenticate users with Username & Password (out of curiosity) but it doesn't seem like this is possible ([described here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/)) from a website/WebAPI (only Native client).

Does anyone know what is the best way to acquire a token for a different user to that of the authenticated user?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the different user you need to act as? Is this a user account that you're using as a service account to access a service? Or is this actually a real user's user account? Is WebAPI 2 yours, or a Microsoft service?

Comment: Hi - yes sure.. the account we need to switch to is a real users account that is used as a service account (to access a service)

Comment: Is the service (WebAPI 2) a service you own? Or is it a third-party (or Microsoft service)? If Microsoft--which service?

Comment: Its our own service in our tenant

Comment: Do you own the code for that service?

Comment: No, we dont own the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you shouldn't want to (and there's a better approach).

In general, a confidential client (e.g. an API) should **never** have an access token on behalf of a user who hasn't actually signed in and granted authorization to the app. For a middle-tier API such as your WebAPI 1, which wants to make an authenticated request to a back-end API (WebAPI 2), you have two options:

1. WebAPI 1 exchanges the access token it received for an access token to WebAPI 2, on behalf of itself *and* the currently signed-in user.
2. WebAPI 1 obtains an access token to WebAPI 2, authenticating *only* as itself.

It sounds like your scenario should fall into the second approach. WebAPI 1 would obtain an app-only access token to WebAPI 2, and use it in requests to WebAPI 2. WebAPI 2, in turn, must understand that an access token can also be only for an app (not a user), and must perform authorization based on the application's identity (rather than a user identity).

With ADAL for .NET, you can obtain an access token on behalf of the client (WebAPI 1, in this case) using either:

- [`AcquireTokenAsync(String, IClientAssertionCertificate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential_), where the client authenticates [using a certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientassertioncertificate?view=azure-dotnet) (best practice).
- [`AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientCredential)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientcredential?view=azure-dotnet), where the client authenticates using a client secret (not best practice).

Comment: Hi Philippe, thank you for your excellent response. I agree with you too. Unfortunately we are constrained in the sense that WebAPI 2 is actually behind AD App Proxy and this service can only work with specific service accounts which forces us to have to switch contexts for the service-to-service hop. Do you have any recommendations for this scenario?

Comment: @cty Ok, two more questions, then: Is your service account (i.e. the user account which is acting as a service account) synced to Azure AD? Is this user account part of a domain name which is federated to AD FS?

Comment: Yes it is - its a sync'd account to Azure AD

Comment: And is the domain name of the user's username a domain which is federated to AD FS?

Comment: Yes, the users username domain is federated with AD FS